# flickering when mouse over, .hover() show/hide div(s)

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show-hide

Good day,

I have these div(s) containers with 2 inner div(s) holding (a) image & (b) text description respectively.

I hide these (b) text description div(s) using .hide() when page load, then using .hover() to show/hide the hidden text description div, sample code below:

```
<div class="projectBlock">
<div class="imgBlock" id="imgBlock1"><a href="http://www.tesco.com.my" target="_blank"><img src="http://i23.photobucket.com/albums/b395/yiyonglee/thumb-project-tesco.jpg"></a>

</div>
<div class="descBlock" id="descBlock1">Tesco Malaysia</div>
```

The show/hide works fine, except if mouseover area hit somewhere inside the descrption text area, the div container flickers while moving around.

my jQuery portion:

```
$('.descBlock').hide();

$('#imgBlock1').hover(function () {
    $('#descBlock1').show();
}, function () {
    $('#descBlock1').hide();
});

$('#imgBlock2').hover(function () {
    $('#descBlock2').show();
}, function () {
    $('#descBlock2').hide();
});
```

Demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLrA/1/)

Why is it acting in such way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you hover over the description, the description hides (because you're not anymore over the #imgBlock). Then you're again over the #imgBlock with your mouse and the description shows up.

Answer (score 4):

Ty this instead:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLrA/3/)

```
$('.descBlock').hide();

$('.projectBlock').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.descBlock').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.descBlock').hide();
});
```

You only have to do it once to affect all the projectBlock elements.

Comment: thanks Vincent, this work just great, and it trims up a big portion of the code too.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, because the overlay block, descBlock{1|2} is obscuring the larger block which you are watching for mouse events.

[See if this is more what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLrA/4/)

By putting in another hover() listener, and having that callback show the child block regardless of whether the mouse is in or out. I only did it for the descBlock1, so you can see the contrast.

```
$('#descBlock1').hover(function () {
 $('#descBlock1').show();
}, function () {
 $('#descBlock1').show();   
});
```

Comment: i tried this before, mouseout doesn't hide #desckBlock1, not really working, thanks anyway.